# Unable to run configure file if not in the same directory

Tags: linux, installation, autotools, configure, autoconf

I am unable to run the configure file for a manual tar.gz package install. For example, after unzipping my file, I run

```
$ sudo ./vim81/configure
[sudo] password for cli2:
./vim81/configure: line 6: cd: src: No such file or directory
```

However, if I am inside the directory where the configure file exists, I am able to run the configure file.

```
$ ./configure
configure: loading cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
...
```

My question is how do I execute the configure file if I am not at the same directory as the source file?

I know I can use `yum` or `apt-get` to install vim, but is just an example package and I want to do this manually for any package. Thanks.

Comment: You should not build with `sudo`. Only use it for `install` if needed. You should perform an `./configure && make && sudo make install`. I don't believe Autotools allows building out-of-tree. You have to run it from the directory where `configure` is. (Maybe newer Autotools are different).

Comment: Why don't you want to `cd` to the dir first?

Comment: @thatotherguy becase I need to write a .NET application to do this under a subprocess for a Linux system.

Comment: So in your subprocess, do a `cd`.  No?

Comment: @cli2 Can you just use [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory) to set the working directory of the process you start?

Comment: @thatotherguy I cannot make any assumptions on the extracted directory's name, for example `vim-8.1.tar.bz2` becomes `vim81` once it is extracted.

Comment: @Nic3500 subprocess can only execute one command at a time. Once the execution ends, the directory will return to where the .NET application is executed for the next subprocess call.

Comment: @jww In my experience, it's a relatively rare package that forbids `configure` to be executed out-of-tree these days… For example, [GCC docs actually recommend configuring outside the source tree](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) entirely, and [glibc's configuration instructions explicitly forbid an in-tree build directory](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html). I haven't had issues building out-of-tree that I can recall, so if I experienced the issue you describe, it was quite a number of years ago.

Comment: @cli2 If you don't know the directory containing the `configure` script, you can't complete this task. Your problem requires knowledge of this directory, whether that means making an assumption or using wildcards. Also, you should only need `sudo` during `make install` as jww explained.

Comment: (continued) As for your error, that is something relatively unique to how Vim is built since its `configure` merely executes `src/configure`, which just executes `src/auto/configure` that was presumably generated by Autoconf from `src/configure.ac`; `src/configure.ac` supposedly works with Autoconf version 2.12 and newer, but 2.12 was released over 20 years ago (November 1996) [according to the GNU FTP server](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/), so Vim is pretty old (1991 according to Wikipedia). I'd recommend [Neovim](https://www.neovim.io) instead, which uses CMake rather than Autotools.

Comment: @cli2 How will you determine the path to configure in the first place then?

Comment: What is the motivation for this in the first place? Are you trying to create a generic package installer that installs tar.gz files? There's a reason why every distro has a package manager instead of doing that.

Comment: You should probably remove the autotools and autoconf tags by the way. This has nothing to do with Autotools since the only executable line in `vim81/configure` is `cd src && ./configure "$@"`, which pretty much just executes `vim81/src/auto/configure`, which _was_ generated by Autoconf but that's not where your error comes from.

Comment: @jww, Automake absolutely does provide for out-of-source building, by default, but it is not free: if they are careless, project maintainers can write Makefile.am files that break out-of-source builds.  Also if, as project maintainer, you use Autoconf without Automake then you're on the hook yourself for any out-of-source building support.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can use `yum` or `apt-get` to install vim, but is just an example package and I want to do this manually for any package.

There is no sure-fire universal recipe for building from source, even if you limit the scope to just Autotools-based packages (which evidently Vim is not, exactly).  This is among the reasons why software packaging, package repositories, and package managers have become so widespread.

As someone who has performed a lot of package building, I assure you that it is a rare joy when I run into a project that I can package up via the equivalent of a straight-up `configure; make; make install`.  When I meet one, it makes my day.  The rest of the time, I have to figure out any number of build details on a per-package basis, such as

- which configuration / build system, *if any*, is in use

  - Autotools / CMake / Python setuptools / etc.
  - This affects the build / install commands needed, and details such as what working directory can / should be used for the build
- which configuration options are needed or appropriate for the target machine(s), and how to express them to the build system

  - can be options to a `configure` script, arguments to `make`, manual tweaks to a `Makefile`, answers to an interactive questionaire, ...
- what dependencies are required, at what versions, and how to get them if I don't already have them
- sometimes, how to clean up post-installation, for example,

  - to remove files I didn't want installed
  - to move files that went to the wrong place (despite best available use of build configuration)
  - to fix file permissions or ownership
- sometimes, additional installation tasks, such as

  - adding shell-configuration files
  - creating symlinks
  - enrolling services with the system's service-control subsystem
  - installing dynamic linker configuration files

All of that applies at least as much to manual builds, too.  If you do not rely on someone else to do that (*i.e.* by using packages built by someone else) then you need to be prepared to do yourself as many of those things as are required for each project you build.  There is no way to automate it from that starting point.